# how to compile input from a for loop into a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

I am using python3 to write a function that asks the user for input a certain number of times and then is supposed to compile all of the inputs into a list. I have been able to get the function to ask for the input with no problem but when I try to print the list, it says there is none.

```
def get_list(t):
n = []
for i in range (1,t+1):
    try:
        x = input("Give me the next integer in the list: ")
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be an integer.")
    n.append(x)   

>>> list1 = get_list(3)
Give me the next integer in the list: 3
Give me the next integer in the list: 43
Give me the next integer in the list: 32
>>> print(list1)
None
```

I have also tried it where it will store the response as a list, but it will only do the function one time:

```
>>> def get_list(t):
n = []
for n in range(t):
    try:
        n = int(input("Give me the next integer in the list: "))
        return n
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be an integer.")
list.append(n)

>>> list1 = get_list(3)
Give me the next integer in the list: 8
>>> list1
8
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a return in your function! Fixing your code like so:

```
def get_list(t):
    n = []
    for i in range (1,t+1):
        try:
            x = input("Give me the next integer in the list: ")
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer.")
        n.append(x)
    return n
```

yields this sample result:

```
>>> y = get_list(3)
Give me the next integer: 1
Give me the next integer: 2 
Give me the next integer: 3
>>> print(y)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about making sure to have a return!